# Should I get a monitor that has a vertical pivoting stand or just get a vertical VESA stand?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, vesa

I'm thinking a monitor that pivots vertically. Unfortunately, I haven't seen many options, so   I thought it might be better to just get a VESA compatible monitor and a VESA stand that pivots vertically.

Anybody done this in the past and has suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your workspace and the monitor you have in mind and the kind of use you'll be putting it to?  That said, this may fall under 'shopping recommendation'...I'm not too sure.  Mods?

Comment: @Shinrai: I suppose in a way it is. Should I just delete? Besides, Mr. Vazquez-Abrams made a good point and I'm already leaning toward getting the stand.

Comment: Workspace: I have a laptop on a desk shelf so it's at eye level. I already have a secondary monitor that is on it's last days. So I'm doing some research on replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

If your desk/wall/whatever can support it then I'd get a decent monitor arm. The flexibility in positioning as well as the ability to get it mostly or completely off the surface are usually worth it.

Comment: Based on updates in comments, I agree.  A good VESA compatible articulating arm with a pivot/swivel/tilt mount will go a LONG way.  (Best to clamp or wall mount so it doesn't risk tipping, especially if you have kids around)